# When we can change the sign of denominator

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

Suppose $z=\frac{-x_1}{x_2-x_3}$, find $-z$.

Which one is correct 
$$-z=\frac{x_1}{x_2-x_3}\ \ \ \text{or}\ \ \ -z=\frac{x_1}{-x_2+x_3}$$

Comment: If $z = \dfrac{-1}{1}$, is it true that $-z = \dfrac{1}{-1}$ or $-z = \dfrac{1}{1}$?

Comment: Remember that $-\frac ab=\frac{-a}b=\frac a{-b}\ne\frac{-a}{-b}$. (What you're trying to do is multiply both sides by $-1$.)

Comment: If $z=\frac{-x_1}{x_2-x_3}$, then $-z = -\left( \frac{-x_1}{x_2-x_3} \right) = \frac{x_1}{x_2-x_3}$

Comment: Try plugging in numbers like $x_1 =1, x_2 =2, x_3 = 3$ and seeing which one works

Comment: Many thanks guys, I get it. Sorry guys I have another question can we write $u''$ like this $u_{xx}$

Comment: @Tony  You can, but the subscript notation is usually preserved for partial derivatives.  It turns out that partial derivatives and "normal" derivatives are the same thing in the one variable case, but I would be careful using that notation on, say, a homework assignment.

Answer (score 4):

We have $z=\frac{-x_1}{x_2-x_3}, \ -z = (-1)\cdot \frac{-x_1}{x_2-x_3}$$$-z = \frac{x_1}{x_2-x_3} =\big(\frac{-1}{1}\big)\cdot \frac{-x_1}{x_2-x_3} = \big(\frac{1}{-1}\big)\frac{-x_1}{x_2-x_3} = \frac{-x_1}{x_3-x_2}$$

Notice that in one of your proposed solutions above you would find the following:
$$\frac{x_1}{x_3-x_2} = \frac{(-1)\cdot (-x_1)}{(-1)\cdot (x_2-x_3)} = \frac{-x_1}{x_2-x_3} = z$$
You may only apply the negative factor to either the numerator or the denominator, but not both because they will negate eachother.